# using extract to extract post dollar variables

Tags: php, extract

Hi im trying to build a foreach of sort of , that would extract($_POST) then utf8_decode each post so i dont have to do this manually for each $ variable, is it easy to make such function, im tired..thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you need to utf8_decode() the data in the first place? Why not e.g. encode the incoming data as `iso-8859-1` from the start? What are you doing with the data afterwards?

Comment: Why do you need to extract all POST variables?

Comment: because jquery ajax does not seems to be flexible if you want to choose a diffrenet charset than UTF

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel   , because it's a form and i want the vars, that's strange?,
form the jquery docs:
Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side.

Comment: @tada good point. It's possible to change the encoding but it's difficult. What are you doing with the data? Putting it into a database?

Comment: yeah. that's strange. Because array is way more handy than bunch of separate variables. Isn't it? Just iterate over this array to get everything you need from this form data

Comment: right putting it in a DB

Comment: @col, sorry i dont get it, for me extract is good it gets everything as $ variable so no need of $email=$_POST["email"]

Comment: I can't tell if this is really what you meant, but just in case: Avoid calling `extract($_POST)`. It's dangerous for the same reasons register_globals is dangerous.

Comment: @tada: don't use the extract method on $_GET and $POST, it's written also on the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing every variable into query by hand, you can just name the field names, by using
this simple function to produce SET statement:

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

and usage as simple as:

```
$fields = explode(" ","name surname lastname address zip fax phone");
$query  = "UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet($fields)." WHERE id=$id";
```

Neat, eh?

Comment: yep looks cool , by the way im pretty new to php, what the substr($set, 0, -2); is for?

Comment: @tada: it's removes the last ", " at the end of the $set variable.

Comment: Nice, but this still needs `utf8_decode()` ing or `iconv()` as requested by the OP ;)